# Замена пикчи. Выбор технологии

Tags: javascript, html, css, изображения

Добрый день. Необходимо по событию заменить картинку на такую же, но другого цвета. Вопрос, что лучше использовать: изменение цвета для свг-фигуры по событию или подгрузку другой пикчи через скрипт?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ и самый надежный на мой взгляд.

```
<img src="/images/Save_16.png"
    onmousemove="src='/images/Save_15.png'" 
    onmouseout="src='/images/Save_16.png'"/>
```